# Differences between multiple OPC UA clients connected to the same OPC UA server

Tags: plc, opc-ua, siemens

I have two OPC clients subbed to about 160 items(temp sensors,pressure sensors,...) on a Siemens PLC(S7 1500) OPC UA server. Each client is on a different machine (one is on-site, other is hosted on cloud).
When we compare results on each client we can see small differences with our data. sometimes there is more data on one computer, sometimes there is more on the other. sometimes values are different for the same timestamp

Here is an example of a compare for 1 item between two clients
[compare of values between two clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr8Wu.png)

We use the SourceTimestamp of the monitored item and its value coming from the OPC server to put it in the database.

This is not a big issue but I would like to understand why there is such a difference between two identical clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've lost a lot of precision using the date/time format in your screenshots. Perhaps it's just a rounding issue and the underlying timestamps aren't exactly the same like you think they are?

Comment: I understand your point, excuse my bad knowledge in automation, but isn't the server supposed to post the same timestamp for a same item value change to each client ? what I imagined, is that the OPC server send to each client "This value has changed to 6 the 2022-08-08 19:00:00.000" ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: That's not how it works internally. Each client creates a Subscription and each of those Subscriptions have MonitoredItems, with each of those items being assigned a Sampling Interval. Internally most servers are just polling the underlying data for each item at the assigned sampling interval, and items from one client, or even within one subscription, may not be polled at exactly the same time as another client/subscription. This is of course all implementation dependent. The expectations you have are not quite correct.